# Excel VBA: Out of Memory Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have two .xlsm workbooks. Only workbook B runs a macro on the other.

```
Workbook A: Job Closeout Status.xlsm
Workbook B: Weekly Payment Sheet.xlsm
```

Workbook B has a pivot table where the data source is workbook A.
The macro on wkbk B refreshes the pivot table when opened.

I am getting an out of memory error. I have researched that I should set objects to nothing. However I can't edit the macro. Every time I try to add a line of code it gives the "out of memory" error. Can anyone help me out on how to optimize performance, and resolve this "out of memory" issue? Thanks.

I have also noticed that in Visual Basics App, when I only have wkbk B open, wkbk A appears in my project explorer and the worksheet icons are highlighted blue. Usually I only see workbooks that are open in project explorer.

[image]

Here is my code in workbook B:

In ThisWorkbook module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RETENTION").Unprotect
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wkb As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
If IsFileOpen("S:\ACCOUNTING\Subcontracts\Job Closeout Tracking\Job Closeout Status.xlsm") Then
    GoTo Protect
Else
On Error Resume Next
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(filename:="S:\ACCOUNTING\Subcontracts\Job Closeout Tracking\Job Closeout Status.xlsm")
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If

Protect:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RETENTION").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In a separate module:

```
Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening with your code, but all of those `On Error Resume Next` lines are a red flag.

Comment: I am running Excel 2013 32-bit. The code has been working. Just need to optimize performance/code I think.

Comment: Where should I start in trying to resolve this?

Comment: If it was working but is not longer working then maybe your workbook and/or project has somehow become corrupt. This seems to be the case if you can't even edit the macros. You can do something like (having made copies of everything to be safe) do things like export the VBA modules and reimport them into a brand-new workbook and then start moving the data over. Maybe someone else has another idea, but if not, Google something like "recovering from corrupt VBA projects" and see if any of the suggestions you read do the trick.

Comment: @ John Coleman I made a copy of the orig, renamed it, erased macro and saved. Put the macro back in and copied over the original in the original location. The seems to have cleared things. Then I removed the on error resume next from everything. Now I'm getting run-time error 91, object variable or with block not set. Need to prevent this from happening again. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What line gives you that error?

Comment: The line that is giving the error is `If IsFileOpen("S:\ACCOUNTING\Subcontracts\Job Closeout Tracking\Job Closeout Status.xlsm") Then`

Comment: So `IsFileOpen` is throwing the error. The way that `On Error Resume Next` is used there makes sense since the error is dealt with and not simply passed over. Evidently error 91 is encountered when you try to open that file (or possible when you try to find a free file number?) and, since 91 isn't 70, the error is re-raised. Are you sure that the file name is correct?

Comment: Yes file name is correct as it's a direct copy paste of the Target path. The macro has been working as intended. If file is open do nothing, if not, open file refresh data connection, close workbook. I might try creating a new workbook if you really think it's corrupted. Any modifications you recommend to my code? Should I remove `On Error Resume Next` after '`Else` or set variables to nothing? Thanks.

Comment: I only get the out of memory error when it tries to open workbook A to refresh data. Workbook A has a lot of data and formulas. Would that use up a lot of memory.

Comment: I started over with a new file, and it's not a corrupt file. Not sure how to fix this.